# Is there a way to remap keys on ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: keyboard, 20.10

I’m using a MacBook Air (late 2010) and need to remap my **enter/return** key to my **right alt**.
Is there a command/ app to do this? Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The terminal tool `xmodmap` should allow to swap keys. Currently, X keyboard extension is used, but that is more complex. For a simple change you can involve xmodmap.

Comment: @vanadium thanks I’ll try that

Comment: This looks like a good guide, showing a method with xmodmap and a method changing the xkb config files.

Comment: Here, reference is made to a gui tool I did not know about: https://www.linuxuprising.com/2020/12/remap-keyboard-and-mouse-buttons-on.html

Comment: So I downloaded the GUI tool you suggested but to set a key, I have to press it, and the whole reason I need a key remapper is because my enter key doesn’t work. It’d be helpful if you gave an official answer and explained how to use xmodmap to remap enter to right alt, cause I’m a bit of a noob when it comes to Linux.